# User Profile: Number of votes cast doesn't add up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, voting

When looking at my "Impact" statistics in my SO User Profile, the number of votes I have cast seems to differ depending on where I look. I've ensured that;

1. "All" votes are showing
2. I clicked directly on "615 votes cast" and that shows the pane underneath, which only shows "509".

Any ideas why these two are different?

[image]

Comment: Aged Away or Retracted perhaps?

Comment: Deleted posts don't show up in the lower section, but do in general stats, like the activity page, or your summary at the bottom of the activity page.

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate, I did try searching for a related topic but my wording must have been inaccurate.